# Examples of Analog and Digital components combined in a circuit design

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, analog, circuit-design

I am working on a presentation about circuit design where I want to convey the importance of combining analog and Microcontroller or digital components in a design to achieve the optimum performance.

This might sound bit weird but here in my study place Analog and Digital circuit design were treated as a separate entities and we haven't been taught how to combine Analog and Digital elements together to achieve optimum design except for interfacing Analog sensors with Microcontrollers.

So I am trying to address in this in my presentation and I need some common examples where Analog and Digital elements are combined in a single design to emphasize my point. I have tried searching around Internet but didn't get what I exactly need?

Can anyone help me with some common examples please?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You haven't found ANY examples on your own, yet? (You didn't present anything you've acquired, yet.) Perhaps you might save us all some time by telling us what you've already figured out. After all, you are the presenter. You should know this stuff, at least to some degree. And if you tell us what you already know then that will save us thinking and typing in what you already have in store. Your question is wide open.

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is "mixed-signal electronics". Google hits some very relevant links. Live long and prosper.

Comment: Have a read: https://www.eeweb.com/profile/e3-designers-llc/articles/mixed-signal-pcb-design-what-is-it Mixed signal is perhaps one of the most challenging PCB design tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You can look for mixed signal microcontroller where differential high speed  analog pins are present.

http://www.ti.com/product/MSP430I2030

or

http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa024/slaa024.pdf

Answer (score 1):

By using simple logic gates like NAND gates you get signals (digital signals i.e. 0 or 1) in its output as a function of the input digital signals. These output signals then can be used to turn on a LED by simply interfacing it with a transistor, which requires a current in its base in order to turn on, then requiring a rated resistor in its base to limit current( walking now through analog field).

There´s another kind of circuit which would maybe help you understand it, which is when you use an ADC or DAC, where the names themselves already say: Analog to Digital Converter(ADC) or Digital to Analog Converter(DAC) that are in general IC´s designed to receive an analog signal, (say from 0 up to 5v) and bring as outcome digital signals (say from 0 up to 255 bits in a 8 bit ADC) and of course vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Flávio Alegretti answer, there are other components, like digital potentiometer, analog multiplexer, pulse width modulator or comparator.